# multiplication method for two polynomials

Tags: java, integer, multiplication

hey guys I have been working on this code but the problem i have now is that it is only multiplying polynomial 1 by the first term of polynomial 2

so 2x + 2 * 5x + 5 = 10x2 + 10x

instead of 10x2 + 20x + 10

and here is the code that does the multiplication:

```
public Polynomial multiply( )
{
    Polynomial res = clone();
    for(Monomial tmp = res.head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        res.addTerm(tmp.coeff *= head.coeff, tmp.deg += head.deg);
    double num = 0.5;
    for(Monomial tmp = res.head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        tmp.coeff *= num;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Start by debugging your code to track down where the problem occurs.

Comment: [sscce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm doesn't appear to be very similar to the algorithm one employs when multiplying polynomials.  If you have two polynomials and you treat them as sequences of monomials (as you appear to be doing), so you have (A1,A2) * (B1,B2), then the result you want looks like (A1*B1, A1*B2, A2*B1, A2*B2) before simplification.  Notice that the product is a cross-product of the original polynomials, containing more monomials than either polynomial started with.  Your use of a simple `for` loop will never result in such a product.

Something along the lines of nested `for` loops may make sense, wherein you iterate over all of the monomials in the first polynomial and then, within that loop, run an inner `for` loop that produces a new monomial that is the product of that monomial and each of the monomials from the second polynomial in turn.

After all of that, you can compare degrees in order to simplify your result by combining monomials.